# Powershell Report to list Hotfixes

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file which I parse out to get KB information that I use to query for the existence of hotfixes after the user applies them in a standalone environment.  I have been successful in making the query work (most of the time) but I would like cleaner output.

The code is pretty basic:

```
    $array = Import-Csv .\2K8R2Patches.csv -header Patchname 
    foreach ($patch in $array){
         $PatchID = $patch -split('-') | Select-String -Pattern "KB"
         $HotFix = Get-HotFix -Id $PatchID -ErrorAction 0;

   if ($HotFix) 
   {

   Get-HotFix -Id $PatchID | Format-Table HotFixID, Description,      InstalledOn -AutoSize | Out-File -Append .\PatchInstalled.txt

}

if (-Not ($HotFix))
{
    Write-Host "Patch" $PatchID "is NOT installed" | Out-File -Append .\PatchInstalled.txt

    }
```

}

The output file looks like this for the patches that are installed:

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3087038 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3069114 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3074543 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3084135 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3087039 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

HotFixID  Description     InstalledOn
--------  -----------     -----------
KB3087918 Security Update 9/21/2015 12:00:00 AM

So as you can see - the data is all there, but I would like it to be more tabular and I am stuck trying to figure that part out.

Comment: First, `Write-Host` explicitly writes data to your Host (usually the PowerShell console or ISE), so it will not pipe anything to your `Out-File` command. Beyond that, why pipe to `Format-Table` and then `Out-File` when a CSV for something like this would be so much better? Are you really just dying to have a text file for it to open in WordPad or something?

Comment: I probably should have left the write-host info out.  I was just making sure that it appeared on the console.  But to answer the other question, yes - the customer site is going to be looking at a notepad/text file that is opened on their screen at the end of the overall script / installation execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an object then export the output to csv or...

```
    $array = Import-Csv .\2K8R2Patches.csv -header Patchname
      $patches = @()
      foreach ($patch in $array) {
          $PatchID = $patch -split('-') | Select-String -Pattern "KB"
          $HotFix = Get-HotFix -Id $PatchID -ErrorAction 0;

           if ($HotFix) 

               {
                   $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

                       HotFixID    = $HotFix.HotFixID
                       Description = $HotFix.Description
                       InstalledOn = $HotFix.InstalledOn   
                   }
               $patches += $object
            }
            Else                
            {
                  $nopatch = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                      HotFixID    = $PatchID
                      InstalledOn = "Not Installed"
                      Description = "Not Installed"  
                  }
               $patches += $nopatch
           }

    }
$patches |select HotFixID, Description, InstalledOn| Out-File mypath\patch.txt
```

Here is the result, if the KB is not installed it will writ "Not installed"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately the output from $patches was blank.  When I looked at the csv file itself the first line was "#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject".  If I dropped out the export and just run $patches at the console the variable has no values, just the headers.

Comment: Thank you.  That ran much better.  I'm getting the data now and between the suggestions from you and TheMadTechnician I am much further down the path!!  I appreciate the help.  I am still getting that first line in my CSV file though and I'm not sure why.  The problem is that the people who look at this data in the field, although they carry the title "administrators" - they aren't.  So I have to keep output dumbed down to the extent possible.  The systems that the data will be displayed on do not have excel - hence the desire for tabulated text.  Again thank you - I'm much further along.

Comment: I have updated my post, now it will export data to text file. If its helped please mark as answer

Comment: The first line I was referring to was the ""#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" line.  However, with your help I was able to get what I needed - much thanks.  I also piped in Format-Table -Autosize to compress the data down.  Between the feedback from you at TheMadTechnician I have a very good solution!!! Thank you both.

Comment: Glad you got it all figured out! By the way, the `If($Hotfix)` part can be shortened to `If($Hotfix){$Patches += $Hotfix | Select Description,InstalledOn,HotFixID}` and then move on to the `Else` portion. No need to create a new `$object` when you can use the one you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's start at the top... a CSV file with 1 column and no header is not a CSV, it's a text file with an identity crisis. Let's just use `Get-Content` instead.

```
$array = Get-Content .\2K8R2Patches.csv
```

Ok, so we have an array of strings that are hyphen separated somehow, and contain a KB# in there. What you are doing with the piping to `Select-String` works, but it's like using a fishing net to catch a baseball: it'll work, but there's better ways to do it. What's happening essentially is that you are breaking each string into an array of strings, and then filtering those strings for anything that contains the letters 'kb' in that order. A `Where` statement will do that better (your method passes blanks when the KB isn't found, a `Where` statement won't do that), and we can refine the RegEx match a bit better to avoid any strings that just might contain the letters KB in that order somewhere in the string. Let's just get an array of the KB's that we want to look for, so we'll wrap that `get-content` command in parenthesis, split it's output just like you were, and pipe that to our `Where` statement! Yeah, that'll be good, we'll just read in the info that we actually want.

```
$array = (Get-Content .\2K8R2Patches.csv) -split "-" | Where{$_ -match "^KB\d+$"}
```

More info on that regex match located at [this RegEx101 link](https://regex101.com/r/aV2sA6/1).

So now we have `$array` that looks something like this:

```
KB3087038
KB3069114
KB3074543
KB3084135
KB3087039
KB3087918
```

Excellent, now I'm going to take a slightly different path than you did. I'm going to gather all of the hotfixes installed on the computer, so that we only have to call the command once. When I tested with the 6 KBs you listed on my machine it took 7.6 seconds to query each KB on it's own (like you did), compared to 1.4 seconds to list all of the hotfixes installed and filter against the list of 6. Then we filter those installed against the list we have in `$array`, and then we'll deal with the missing KB's.

```
[array]$HotFixes = Get-HotFix | Where{$array -contains $_.HotFixID}
```

Ok, that's the ones we have, now for the hotfixes that aren't installed. Note that I specified that `$HotFixes` is an array, so even if it only finds 1 installed hotfix, it'll be an array with 1 item (or an empty array if none are found). That's important, so that we can add more items to that array for each of the not-installed hotfixes. So that it outputs nicely I'm going to create objects for each hotfix that isn't installed, and each object will have the properties that we are going to output from the hotfixes that we do have: HotFixID, Description, InstalledOn

```
$array | Where{$HotFixes.HotfixID -notcontains $_} | ForEach{$HotFixes += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    'HotFixID' = $_
    'Description' = 'Not Installed'
    'InstalledOn' = ''
    }}
```

Now, we have all of the hotfixes that you imported, and if we export to a CSV it outputs nicely to be reviewed in Excel (after column widths are adjusted).

```
$Hotfixes | Export-CSV .\2K8R2Hotfixes.csv -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item .\2K8R2Hotfixes.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The CSV file is used in other parts of an installer so it does contain multiple columns but has no headers.  Agree that it's a text file with an identity crisis, but it's a legacy problem that I'm not trying to fix at this very moment.  As I indicated in my other comment above I really need the output in text / column format if possible so that it can be opened on the user's screen in notepad (actually notepad will be launched automatically).   I'll post back after I've had the chance to test your suggestions.  Thanks!!!